# How to setup 2 CMake targets for a single executable with different post build actions?

Tags: cmake

I am working on an embedded project managed with CMake and I would like to do different actions on the same executable.

Consider I have the following project:

```
/cmake/foo.cmake
/CMakeLists.txt
/main.cpp
```

Irrelevant `main.cpp` for this question:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `foo.cmake` file contains a function:

```
function(print_executable_size TARGET_NAME)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${TARGET_NAME}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND size ${TARGET_NAME}.exe
    )
endfunction()
```

The main `CMakeLists.txt` has the following content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(proj)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
include(foo)

add_executable(pgm-dev main.cpp)
add_executable(pgm-prod ALIAS pgm-dev)

# this line works but this is not needed when compiling the "dev" program.
print_executable_size(pgm-dev)

# Uncomment this line leads to TARGET 'pgm-prod' was not created in this directory.
# print_executable_size(pgm-prod)
```

**My ideal build process would be to have:**

- a cmake target "pgm-dev" that just build the executable,
- a cmake target "pgm-prod" that re-build the "pgm-dev" executable if necessary AND do some POST_BUILD actions.

**Why having two targets "pgm-dev" and "pgm-prod"?**

Consider the "pgm-prod" does some extra build actions like cipher the produced binary so, no need to do it in everyday development.

**Why use a cmake file with a function instead of `add_custom_command()` right after executable?**

I have multiple executables concerned in my whole project and I would like to avoid code duplications.

**Why not creating another executable, with a different name?**

"pgm-dev" and "pgm-prod" are exactly compiled the same way, only post build actions differ.

---

I thought using `add_executable(.. ALIAS ..)` would be great for this but it seems I'm not understanding some key points here. What would be the best CMake approach to do what I want?

Comment: '"pgm-dev" and "pgm-prod" are exactly compiled the same way, only post build actions differ.' - A post build action becomes **part of the executable target**. If you want **different actions** for an executable, then you need to create **different targets**. Command `add_executable(ALIAS)` doesn't create a *copy* of the target, it creates "*symlink*" to the existed target. And for avoid confusion, CMake prohibits using a symlink for change the target. If you want to avoid compiling the same files twice, then you could use STATIC or OBJECT library.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a key point I didn't understood till today, especially this "A post build action becomes part of the executable target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create an alias. Instead create a [custom target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) that executes the commands and [add a dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) to the executable target

```
add_executable(pgm-dev main.cpp)

add_custom_target(pgm-prod COMMAND size $<TARGET_FILE:pgm-dev>)
add_dependency(pgm-prod pgm-dev)
```

This way cmake makes sure that `pgm-dev` is built before the command is executed.

---

If you need to more than one of those commands to all be executed, you could introduce intermediate targets that execute the command that depend on the original target and create a target for executing all those commands that depends on all of those:

```
function(pgm_add_custom_postbuild_command ORIGINAL_TARGET NEW_TARGET SUFFIX)
    if(NOT TARGET ${ORIGINAL_TARGET})
        add_custom_target(${ORIGINAL_TARGET})
    endif()
    add_custom_target(pgm_internal_${ORIGINAL_TARGET}_${SUFFIX} ${ARGN})

    # hide away target in a dedicated folder, if folders are activated in the IDE
    set_target_properties(pgm_internal_${ORIGINAL_TARGET}_${SUFFIX} PROPERTIES FOLDER PgmInternal)

    add_dependencies(pgm_internal_${ORIGINAL_TARGET}_${SUFFIX} ${ORIGINAL_TARGET})
    add_dependencies(${NEW_TARGET} pgm_internal_${ORIGINAL_TARGET}_${SUFFIX})
endfunction()

function(pgm_print_size ORIGINAL_TARGET NEW_TARGET)
    pgm_add_custom_postbuild_command(${ORIGINAL_TARGET} ${NEW_TARGET} size
        COMMAND size $<TARGET_FILE:${ORIGINAL_TARGET}>)
endfunction()

function(pgm_print_md5sum ORIGINAL_TARGET NEW_TARGET)
    pgm_add_custom_postbuild_command(${ORIGINAL_TARGET} ${NEW_TARGET} md5sum
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E md5sum $<TARGET_FILE:${ORIGINAL_TARGET}>)
endfunction()
```

```
pgm_print_size(pgm-dev pgm-prod)
pgm_print_md5sum(pgm-dev pgm-prod)
```

Comment: Thank you, that suits perfectly my needs